# Keep last n characters of cells in a function in R

Tags: r, function

Consider the following data.frame:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(rep("text_2010"),rep(1,5)), c("id", "value"))
```

I only want to keep the 4 last characters of the cells in the column "id". Therefore, I can use the following code:

```
df$id <- substr(df$id,nchar(df$id)-3,nchar(df$id))
```

However, I want to create a function that does the same. Therefore, I create the following function and apply it:

```
testfunction <- function(x) {
  x$id <- substr(x$id,nchar(x$id)-3,nchar(x$id))
}

df <- testfunction(df)
```

But I do not get the same result. Why is that?

Comment: Add `return(x)` in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return(x)` in your function to return the changed object.

```
testfunction <- function(x) {
  x$id <- substr(x$id,nchar(x$id)-3,nchar(x$id))
  return(x)
}

df <- testfunction(df)
```

However, you don't need an explicit `return` statement always (although it is better to have one). R by default returns the last line in your function so here you can also do

```
testfunction <- function(x) {
  transform(x, id = substring(id, nchar(id)-3))
}

df <- testfunction(df)
```

which should work the same.

Answer (score 2):

We can also create a function that takes an argument `n` (otherwise, the function would be static for the `n` and only useful as a dynamic function for different data) and constructs a regex pattern to be used with `sub`

```
testfunction <- function(x, n) {
     pat <- sprintf(".*(%s)$", strrep(".", n))
     x$id <- sub(pat, "\\1", x$id)
  return(x)
 }
```

-testing

```
testfunction(df, n = 4)
#     id value
#1 2010     1
#2 2010     1
#3 2010     1
#4 2010     1
#5 2010     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution attempting to mirror Excel's `RIGHT()` function:

```
# Function to extract the right n characters from each element of a provided vector: 
right <- function(char_vec, n = 1){
  # Check if vector provided isn't of type character: 
  if(!is.character(char_vec)){
    # Coerce it, if not: char_vec => character vector
    char_vec <- vapply(char_vec, as.character, "character")
  }
  # Store the number of characters in each element of the provided vector: 
  # num_chars => integer vector
  num_chars <- nchar(char_vec)
  # Return the right hand n characters of the string: character vector => Global Env() 
  return(substr(char_vec, (num_chars + 1) - n, num_chars))
}

# Application: 
right(df$id, 4)
```

Data:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(rep("text_2010"),rep(1,5)), c("id", "value"))
```